# Why WordPress convert my webP images into JPG?

Tags: wordpress, jpeg, webp

ENVIRONMENT: WP Version 6.4.1

When I want to upload a webp image in my woocommerce product, WordPress converts my webP image into JPG.

So I deactivated all the plugins and tried to upload my webP from the Media Manager => I got the same issue.

I activated another theme to check if it was my theme source of this issue, but I got the same issue with other themes.

This is weird as it was working fine before.

Does anyone have this issue? How can I fix that?

Comment: WordPress 5.8+ has had support for native WebP images. There is no conversion code in core that would result in this behavior. Verified on my install. Something non-vanilla must doing the conversions: the theme, some plugins, mu-plugins?